# Binomial coefficient properties

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factorial

On "theoretical computer science cheat sheet" I found a special formula which is:
$$ {n \choose k} = (-1)^k {k-n-1 \choose k}$$

But when I try to expand the value of ${k-n-1 \choose k}$ I have
$${k-n-1 \choose k} = \frac{(k-n-1)!}{k!(k-n-1-k)!} = \frac{(k-n-1)!}{k!(-n-1)!}$$
And I am very confused with the factor $(-n-1)!$, because I can count factorial only for positive values, and value $-n-1$ is negative. Can someone explain where I am making a mistake in my thinking?

Comment: Never seen this before, but I think that here e.g. $(-4)! := (-4)*(-3)*(-2)*(-1) = (-1)^4*4!$ Then it should fit ..

Comment: The formula is meant to help you understand n-choose-k when n is negative. One uses a definition of the binomial coefficient that doesn't require taking factorial of a negative number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But on this paper, there is no adnotation that n have to be negative. So it has to be positive, so still I don't understand where is a mistake in my thinking

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 But wolfram gives that (-4)! is infinity

Comment: I never said $n$ *has* to be negative, and the formula is correct whether $n$ is negative or not, but it is useful mostly when $n$ is negative. But see my answer.

Comment: Your mistake is the reflex to use the formula with factorials to approach binomial coefficients. It is very often a mistake (not always, but the occasions where it is actually useful are rare). You should also be aware that the formula is only really valid in the "positive cone" (Pascal's triangle). See the answer by Gerry Myerson for a better alternative.

Comment: Suggestion: Knuth, *The Art of Computer Programming*.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are missing is that there is a way to express binomial coefficients without factorials, and this expression works even when some of the terms are negative. Thus: $${n\choose r}={n(n-1)(n-2)\times\cdots\times(n-r+1)\over r!}$$ This formula agrees with the usual one when $n\ge0$, and works even when $n\lt0$, without asking you to compute any factorials of negative numbers. And this formula is what is behind the one on the "cheat sheet".